# User-friendly way to allow Google Analytics access?

Tags: google-analytics, oauth, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

We're about to implement processing Google Analytics report data in a web application.

Is there a "consent window way" to grant access rather than having to manually generate access tokens and configuring access to report views?

Comment: Have you tried presenting the data via Google Data Studio? That lets you provide access to anyone you like just by copying a URL (no tokens or user configuration required). Maybe that's not secure enough for you, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics data is private user data.  In order to access a users data you must have their permission.  To gain the permission of a user you request their consent to your application accessing their data.

To do this we use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) there is no other way to access a users data you are going to have to request consent of the user.  Oauth2 always shows a constant screen to the user the first time

Comment: Hey Dalm. I might have been unclear on that. Is there an oauth2 browser dialog for asking permission, and if there is, could you link to the docs? I couldn't find any.

Comment: [Google Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)  Oauth2 always shows a constant screen.   what language are you using see if you can find a client library for it